# Getting different results for 'class()' method

Tags: r

Here's the smallest piece of code which displays how i am getting different results for class() when called directly for columns vs when called using apply.

data.frame looks like this.

```
> df
    A             B             C
1 rlm  4.047317e-03  0.0040111713
2 rlm -6.474359e-02 -0.0657461598
3 rlm  1.464302e-01  0.1451224214
4 rlm  3.508878e-01  0.3477540761
5  lm  2.701757e-01  0.2769367280
6  lm  2.580785e-03  0.0025815525
7 rlm  1.638077e-05  0.0000160895

> str(df)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: chr  "rlm" "rlm" "rlm" "rlm" ...
     $ B: num  0.00405 -0.06474 0.14643 0.35089 0.27018 ...
 $ C: num  0.00401 -0.06575 0.14512 0.34775 0.27694 ...

> class(df$A)
    [1] "character"
    > class(df$B)
[1] "numeric"
> apply(df, 2, class)
          A           B           C 
"character" "character" "character"
```

So, when called directly class of B is 'numeric', but when called using apply, it's saying 'character'.

Am i missing anything here ?

Comment: Apply coerces data.frame to matrix. Unlike data.frame all entries in a matrix need to have the same class. Since you can always convert numeric to character but not vice versa you get a character matrix. You want to look at lapply and sapply since data.frames are basically lists with the columns as entries. However, as a pure R language question this is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Why it's off-topic ? Doesn't this discuss what's happening internally in R ?

Comment: Yes, but pure R questions without statistics content are off-topic on cross validated which is more about principles and less about software tools, unless it concerns a peculiarity of a particular implementation of a statistical algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply coerces data.frames to matrices before applying the function. Since in a matrix each element must have the same class you end up with a character matrix (since you can convert numeric to character without information loss but not the other way). The reason for this is probably that you can apply functions by-row as well, which would be messy with data.frames since your function would need to operate on a list.

For what you want check out the lapply and sapply functions, since data.frames are basically lists with each element of the list being one of the columns.

```
> x <- data.frame(a = "Entry", b = 5)
> sapply(x, class)
        a         b 
 "factor" "numeric"
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same result. I think it might be the same behavior you see in this example:

```
number_m <- matrix(1:6)
mode(number_m) # "numeric"

number_m[2,1] <- "b"
mode(number_m) # "character"
number_m
```

converting one element of a matrix or vector to a character changes the data type of all the elements.

I get the correct result using a loop:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
    A             B             C
1 rlm  4.047317e-03  0.0040111713
2 rlm -6.474359e-02 -0.0657461598
3 rlm  1.464302e-01  0.1451224214
4 rlm  3.508878e-01  0.3477540761
5  lm  2.701757e-01  0.2769367280
6  lm  2.580785e-03  0.0025815525
7 rlm  1.638077e-05  0.0000160895")

sapply(1:3, function(i) class(df[,i]))
```

Comment: Matrices are nothing but vectors with dimension as attributes, so you can't have fields with different data type in it. My example's is having data.frame.

Comment: Erik's comment shows better what I was trying to say: I was comparing the behaviour of apply to what happens in a matrix when changing data type.

Comment: You don't need the indexing in `sapply`, you can just use: `sapply(df, class)`